# Centering HTML body element with varying text sizes in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm running into problems trying to center a body element with CSS. I want it to be centered both horizontally and vertically on the page. The problem is that how it's written right now, it will center the text for short messages (i.e. under three words), but longer messages mess it up.

Here's my CSS: (it's an erb file for Sinatra, but I don't think that should impact how the CSS is interpreted)

```
body {
  background: white;

  /*TODO: still not perfect; changes based on length of message */
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -100px;
  margin-left: -100px;
}
.message {
  color: #2f4f4f;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 36;
  text-align: center;
}
.form {
  text-align: center;
}
input[type=number]{
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #2f4f4f;
  background: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2f4f4f;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
}
input[type=number]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
#btn{
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML where the issue is occurring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
body {
    /* ... */
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Please make sure you remove the margin.

Comment: I'd like to add an improvement to this answer, according to conventions the property with the longest prefix should come first, so the order is webkit, moz, ms, o, and the actual non-prefixed property.

Comment: Yeah, I wrote this on my phone so I didn't really bother with that and wrote the prefixes in the order they came to my mind. I fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try use 'flexbox' to your page

```css
.container {
 display: flex;
 height: 500px;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="content">
  Content
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: flex`

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

[Demo](https://codeide.co/master/kHzNdmyM)

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="test">
   <div class="content">
    <p class="para">test test test</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.test { }
.para {
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
   padding-top: 10px;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```